# Android app performance measurement/profiling in production

Tags: android, performance, profiling, performance-testing

I have an android library which will be deployed in many 3rd party apps.
I'd like to know how much memory is being consumed, how much of the cpu is being utilized, battery consumed, etc by my library code in the users' phones.

So I'm thinking I'd do this by making a db model and storing relevant info in the db and sync it once a day or couple of days.

And on this, I have a few questions:

1. Is this a good idea?
2. Has anyone done this before? What are the parameters to be taken into consideration while doing this?
3. Is there a library project somewhere out there which does just this?